# Developing an Alexa skill in python but getting response "There was a problem with the requested skill's response"

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I'm trying to make my first Alexa skill and I'm stuck, all help would be appreciated. I used the default hello world template using Python (only because I'm on a bit of a python kick).

I am trying to create a new intent called "NewChat" and add it but get stuck. When I go to modify the code I get a failure on the skill.

I tried to start slow and add in a new function with no references and get the message "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" Here is the function I tried to add. If I remove this code and re-deploy the skill works.

```
class StartNewChat():
"""Handler to Start New Chat Intent."""
def textOutput:
    return "Hello World!"
```

But I get the following errors in the device log next time I attempt to launch the skill with the above code.

**Directive: SkillDebugger.CaptureDebuggingInfo:**

```
{
"header": {
    "namespace": "SkillDebugger",
    "name": "CaptureDebuggingInfo",
    "messageId": "bdb02573-22a1-430b-b723-1434e1374e99"
},
"payload": {
    "skillId": "amzn1.ask.skill.2ea55c56-f0c9-4369-905e-a9517920455b",
    "timestamp": "2023-01-25T20:19:14.003Z",
    "dialogRequestId": "02a835a3-6fd8-4efe-b71f-bfc0176966c6",
    "skillRequestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.a4db6e19-99bc-491e-a8b6-d7ed5cf718a2",
    "type": "SkillExecutionInfo",
    "content": {
        "invocationRequest": {
            "endpoint": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:443431490338:function:2ea55c56-f0c9-4369-905e-a9517920455b:Release_0",
            "body": {
                "version": "1.0",
                "session": {
                    "new": true,
                    "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.2e351cae-0fa4-4b53-9524-b4c232b46653",
                    "application": {
                        "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.2ea55c56-f0c9-4369-905e-a9517920455b"
                    },
                    "attributes": {},
                    "user": {
                        "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AGXD2SY2ATZSGISXX6UTGFX5UBMT4Z2VQ5LH4B4EIOIAQ5E4QT2AWXI7LYG74KLKITKOQC7U37QF47GYSKWPHXOLUNZFFZWLNHTB3HELTGXCC2ZPHBH4GADSAYZWBYRFG2F2IXOIODJBFLCF3RUKB5RJ4KPQ4PRTXCFDYKT42ZULDJ6KZHL53RIWBVBNU3LGPUP6OFK6HGONPCY"
                    }
                },
                "context": {
                    "Viewports": [
                        {
                            "type": "APL",
                            "id": "main",
                            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
                            "dpi": 213,
                            "presentationType": "STANDARD",
                            "canRotate": false,
                            "configuration": {
                                "current": {
                                    "mode": "HUB",
                                    "video": {
                                        "codecs": [
                                            "H_264_42",
                                            "H_264_41"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "size": {
                                        "type": "DISCRETE",
                                        "pixelWidth": 1280,
                                        "pixelHeight": 800
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "Viewport": {
                        "experiences": [
                            {
                                "arcMinuteWidth": 346,
                                "arcMinuteHeight": 216,
                                "canRotate": false,
                                "canResize": false
                            }
                        ],
                        "mode": "HUB",
                        "shape": "RECTANGLE",
                        "pixelWidth": 1280,
                        "pixelHeight": 800,
                        "dpi": 213,
                        "currentPixelWidth": 1280,
                        "currentPixelHeight": 800,
                        "touch": [
                            "SINGLE"
                        ],
                        "video": {
                            "codecs": [
                                "H_264_42",
                                "H_264_41"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "Extensions": {
                        "available": {
                            "aplext:backstack:10": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "System": {
                        "application": {
                            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.2ea55c56-f0c9-4369-905e-a9517920455b"
                        },
                        "user": {
                            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AGXD2SY2ATZSGISXX6UTGFX5UBMT4Z2VQ5LH4B4EIOIAQ5E4QT2AWXI7LYG74KLKITKOQC7U37QF47GYSKWPHXOLUNZFFZWLNHTB3HELTGXCC2ZPHBH4GADSAYZWBYRFG2F2IXOIODJBFLCF3RUKB5RJ4KPQ4PRTXCFDYKT42ZULDJ6KZHL53RIWBVBNU3LGPUP6OFK6HGONPCY"
                        },
                        "device": {
                            "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AHZKJW64FSL7XGGAEC2FIJR6JS4KHA4XQ7FHF3EZJTYXUSIHLIEGVLKNJS3PRWWU3XKHZPGAGI6WX6T43BRICRPPABGAVFIBD3Q7QOGM762WABILCMRMFNUJRNVP4HNJJBY3S47Z7VC7ZHIGUD3WQ6E2UGNZRCQFRQYR2FJ77IRHK3YQNTZOC",
                            "supportedInterfaces": {}
                        },
                        "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
                        "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.SxtsysBjH7v7OC-FmabEOQRHI0pPIZMOmabSMF3lKuzk9jlQTd29kCVFYf4guFePchPOVkh_kUyCym6i74hKgQ7AhaHcMjKaDkirgOcXaJCjqZpMf4WpojrjyAsxtkmaOUlGUX-KafAuRuHST0j8R4ckHEr_N0vzzh4xidfBZ3f0hNQvn6UoyxePFPxQpTWAvmffljWg_MyOCJZZAofuYE9KjBOGNi9cSLU-451JPkmhyl1p0kl2lbY-V798eTqbLxY5hXtvDr0ePT-lWzuL07-t5_mbziqg2S7LEgtUtF8p6GxoKbJ3ApIHpcAb4W6Jg6brfCO84gn1CRsTDe7B5g"
                    }
                },
                "request": {
                    "type": "LaunchRequest",
                    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.a4db6e19-99bc-491e-a8b6-d7ed5cf718a2",
                    "locale": "en-US",
                    "timestamp": "2023-01-25T20:19:13Z",
                    "shouldLinkResultBeReturned": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Directive: SkillDebugger.CaptureError:**

```
{
"header": {
    "namespace": "SkillDebugger",
    "name": "CaptureError",
    "messageId": "3eaffe12-32bf-430a-9352-6d8bb143b1f6"
},
"payload": {
    "skillId": "amzn1.ask.skill.2ea55c56-f0c9-4369-905e-a9517920455b",
    "timestamp": "2023-01-25T20:19:14.343Z",
    "dialogRequestId": "02a835a3-6fd8-4efe-b71f-bfc0176966c6",
    "skillRequestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.a4db6e19-99bc-491e-a8b6-d7ed5cf718a2",
    "code": "SKILL_ENDPOINT_ERROR",
    "description": "Skill execution returned an exception for requestId amzn1.echo-api.request.a4db6e19-99bc-491e-a8b6-d7ed5cf718a2",
    "debuggingInfo": {
        "type": "SkillExecutionInfo",
        "content": {
            "invocationRequest": {
                "endpoint": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:443431490338:function:2ea55c56-f0c9-4369-905e-a9517920455b:Release_0",
                "body": {
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "session": {
                        "new": true,
                        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.2e351cae-0fa4-4b53-9524-b4c232b46653",
                        "application": {
                            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.2ea55c56-f0c9-4369-905e-a9517920455b"
                        },
                        "attributes": {},
                        "user": {
                            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AGXD2SY2ATZSGISXX6UTGFX5UBMT4Z2VQ5LH4B4EIOIAQ5E4QT2AWXI7LYG74KLKITKOQC7U37QF47GYSKWPHXOLUNZFFZWLNHTB3HELTGXCC2ZPHBH4GADSAYZWBYRFG2F2IXOIODJBFLCF3RUKB5RJ4KPQ4PRTXCFDYKT42ZULDJ6KZHL53RIWBVBNU3LGPUP6OFK6HGONPCY"
                        }
                    },
                    "context": {
                        "Viewports": [
                            {
                                "type": "APL",
                                "id": "main",
                                "shape": "RECTANGLE",
                                "dpi": 213,
                                "presentationType": "STANDARD",
                                "canRotate": false,
                                "configuration": {
                                    "current": {
                                        "mode": "HUB",
                                        "video": {
                                            "codecs": [
                                                "H_264_42",
                                                "H_264_41"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "size": {
                                            "type": "DISCRETE",
                                            "pixelWidth": 1280,
                                            "pixelHeight": 800
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "Viewport": {
                            "experiences": [
                                {
                                    "arcMinuteWidth": 346,
                                    "arcMinuteHeight": 216,
                                    "canRotate": false,
                                    "canResize": false
                                }
                            ],
                            "mode": "HUB",
                            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
                            "pixelWidth": 1280,
                            "pixelHeight": 800,
                            "dpi": 213,
                            "currentPixelWidth": 1280,
                            "currentPixelHeight": 800,
                            "touch": [
                                "SINGLE"
                            ],
                            "video": {
                                "codecs": [
                                    "H_264_42",
                                    "H_264_41"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "Extensions": {
                            "available": {
                                "aplext:backstack:10": {}
                            }
                        },
                        "System": {
                            "application": {
                                "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.2ea55c56-f0c9-4369-905e-a9517920455b"
                            },
                            "user": {
                                "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AGXD2SY2ATZSGISXX6UTGFX5UBMT4Z2VQ5LH4B4EIOIAQ5E4QT2AWXI7LYG74KLKITKOQC7U37QF47GYSKWPHXOLUNZFFZWLNHTB3HELTGXCC2ZPHBH4GADSAYZWBYRFG2F2IXOIODJBFLCF3RUKB5RJ4KPQ4PRTXCFDYKT42ZULDJ6KZHL53RIWBVBNU3LGPUP6OFK6HGONPCY"
                            },
                            "device": {
                                "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AHZKJW64FSL7XGGAEC2FIJR6JS4KHA4XQ7FHF3EZJTYXUSIHLIEGVLKNJS3PRWWU3XKHZPGAGI6WX6T43BRICRPPABGAVFIBD3Q7QOGM762WABILCMRMFNUJRNVP4HNJJBY3S47Z7VC7ZHIGUD3WQ6E2UGNZRCQFRQYR2FJ77IRHK3YQNTZOC",
                                "supportedInterfaces": {}
                            },
                            "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
                            "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.SxtsysBjH7v7OC-FmabEOQRHI0pPIZMOmabSMF3lKuzk9jlQTd29kCVFYf4guFePchPOVkh_kUyCym6i74hKgQ7AhaHcMjKaDkirgOcXaJCjqZpMf4WpojrjyAsxtkmaOUlGUX-KafAuRuHST0j8R4ckHEr_N0vzzh4xidfBZ3f0hNQvn6UoyxePFPxQpTWAvmffljWg_MyOCJZZAofuYE9KjBOGNi9cSLU-451JPkmhyl1p0kl2lbY-V798eTqbLxY5hXtvDr0ePT-lWzuL07-t5_mbziqg2S7LEgtUtF8p6GxoKbJ3ApIHpcAb4W6Jg6brfCO84gn1CRsTDe7B5g"
                        }
                    },
                    "request": {
                        "type": "LaunchRequest",
                        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.a4db6e19-99bc-491e-a8b6-d7ed5cf718a2",
                        "locale": "en-US",
                        "timestamp": "2023-01-25T20:19:13Z",
                        "shouldLinkResultBeReturned": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "metrics": {
                "skillExecutionTimeInMilliseconds": 340
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought maybe it was a compiler error because the class was unreferenced. Except even when I reference StartNewChat().textOutput in the return of the working HelloWorldIntentHandler class that also failed. This is me boiling this down but originally I dove right in, created a new intention with some utterances and copied the HelloWorldIntentHandler to a NewChatHandler and copied the line with the add_request_handler. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to debug this than using the "Device Log" in the testing tab? It shouldn't be this difficult.

Answer (score 2):

So my answer to this was use a proper IDE, I got Alexa Skill Toolkit in VS Code. I find it easier to deal with json files anyway than trying to do it WYSIWYG anyway. Found errors in my code. Now that I'm sorted I'm just slowly making changes, unfortunately there's still not any good debugging info but I'm able to slowly commit, deploy and test... until I have a problem I can't figure out I'm stuck doing it this way. If you're in the same boat try and find an extension for your preferred IDE.